# Can you abbreviate an app title for viewing in app drawer, but still launch it from its full name using google now?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-now

For example if my app name was `Really Long App Name` the complete name might not be shown under the app icon. Say I wanted to condense that to `RLAN` under the app icon, but make it still accessible through a google now command like launch `Really Long App Name`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<activity
  android:name="come.example.MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/activity_title"<!--activity title : your short title-->
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name"> <!--application name : your long title-->
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Since you were able to help me tremendously with this maybe you can answer my other question. Is there a way to have an app launch by saying "Really Long App Name" instead of "Open Really Long App Name"? This is more targeted towards Android Wear where google has preset intents like call a cab that you can trigger by adding the appropriate intent filter to your app. Is there any way to add an app name to that list as an intent so you don't have to prefix it with "open/start" or is that list only something google can manipulate?